# CMS, CAdES_T, XAdES / XAdES_T, PAdES

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am new in digital signature.
I would know if CMS, CAdES_T, XAdES / XAdES_T, PAdES documents have all .p7m extension. If yes, how can I determine the type of signature from .p7m?
BouncyCastle library could be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p7m` files are usually used to hold  encrypted email messages in S/MIME format. See https://fileinfo.com/extension/p7m

CMS, CAdES, XAdES and PAdES are different digital signature formats not related with S/MIME. BouncyCastle supports directly S/MIME and CMS, and indirectly CAdES and PAdES, because they contain a CMS signature, but it does not support XAdES (XML signature format)

Therefore, you can use BouncyCastle to read a .p7m file containing a S/MIME message, but you will need additional libraries to support XAdES, CAdES and PAdES if this is the real purpose